# Averaging duplicates values in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

So I have a dataframe:

[image]

However, there are many duplicated values in the dataframe, after I found out which one are duplicated:

```
Data[Data.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

I got a list of which entries are duplicated:

[image]

My question is as follows: how can I get averaged values of the duplicated entries and compress them into a single entry for each duplicated entry in the original dataframe?

Example: The Maryland entry would have a single Data_Value that is an average of all the Maryland entries etc.

Thank you

Comment: `df.groupby('LocationDesc').mean()`.

Comment: please replace the images of your data with a textual representation that someone can copy-paste into an interpreter. your post will get more participation and is more likely to get a solution that way.

Comment: @HaleemurAli Understood, thank you!